# Moderators... on Cross Validated

Tags: discussion, moderation, rules

Suppose there is a question, "How to get started with applying item response theory and what software to use?"

Suppose the top-rated answer cites my name and work a couple of times.

Suppose all answers discuss software, which is what the question asked about.

Suppose I have a new piece of software, and I tell people about it, as this was what they asked.

Suppose my answer gets immediately deleted by a moderator with a message, "We're glad to have you, but unfortunately this isn't the place for such a description of your software." Did the person even read the original question, in the first place? Would he or she be qualified to understand the value of an immensely complicated psychometric package being released, free of charge, to the community?

And -- what can you do?

And -- who and how defines "overt"? How is a single recommendation of a freely available software package, provided as an answer to a question about such packages, on a page that discusses packages top to bottom, "overt"?

Comment: Post on the Cross-Validated meta, for starters.

Comment: @muru not possible with 1 rep and no questions.

Comment: Do you not think you might have fallen foul of the [avoid overt self-promotion rule](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Good of you to mention that page. What I know is that "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are: commentary on the question or other answers; asking another, different question; “thanks!” or “me too!” responses; exact duplicates of other answers; barely more than a link to an external site; not even a partial answer to the actual question.

Comment: Deciding whether a mention of a new product, in answer to a question about products, on a page that discusses products top to bottom, offends against an "overt self-promotion rule" is a bit... arbitrary... don't you think?

Comment: @IAP Perhaps the question itself was off-topic. Asking for off site resources or recommendations is off topic on almost all sites.

Comment: The dictionary defines overt: done or shown openly; plainly apparent. You don't seem to be denying that you recommended your own psychometric package.

Comment: Deny it? I was trying to be helpful, for the last time in this hostile environment.

Comment: @IAP Which action do you percieve as hostile - the deletion of your answer or the comments on this meta question?

Comment: Every action of biting a helping hand. I not only answer a big question, I provide the means, the complete solution, I get censored, and then the whole thing goes into a discussion of my character, my lowly motives, and of the infinite valor and insight of the moderators. Two of their species advise me to go to meta.CV, presumably in full knowledge of the fact that I cannot post there as a "beginner" (of 30 years professional experience BTW). Comments to deleted answers are disabled, my mouth shut very efficiently. So I leave this nice forum, no need to ban me, I am going, I am gone.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should accept the action by that presumably elected moderator.

On most sites I think a question titled along the lines of "How to get started with [insert topic] and what software to use?" would be closed as Too Broad for focused Q&A or too likely to result in opinions.

On such sites, rather than provide answers to questions seeking a list of answers, I think that you should flag/vote for them to be closed.

Some communities respond to such closure by creating Community Wiki posts for such topics instead but I rarely see such posts maintained, and so they seem quickly to go out of date.